# Is it possible to set the same base for categories and tags?

Tags: url-rewriting

*Note: This question is not about best practices or if it's smart to do this at all, but rather if it's possible*

So I know I can do `add_rewrite_rule('^about/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?tag=$matches[1]', 'top');` to make `/about/` the new tag base instead of `/tag/`. 
Same goes for categories just changing the `tag=$matches[1]` to `category_name=$matches[1]`.

But if I try to do both, the tag base stops working and I just get a 404 page when trying to access the "archive". Is there a way around this?

Comment: No. WP uses URLs to determine what content type to display. If you have two set to the same URL, only one will end up being displayed.

Comment: How would it know the difference between a tag and a category with the same slug?

Comment: @TomJNowell for this question (and what also should usually be the case) I'm gonna assume there's never 2 identical slugs. But if WebEleaine is correct then the whole question is moot.

Comment: then swap that out for how will it know to use the category rewrite rule, or the tag rewrite rule. If this was trivial to do we'd all be doing it and it'd have worked out of the box

Comment: Yea I guess you're right. I think I got my hopes up with the `This can either be 'top' or 'bottom'. 'top' will take precedence over WordPress's existing rules, where 'bottom' will check all other rules match first.` for the $after part. Like I thought that maybe it checks one and if it doesn't find a match it'll move forward or something... Thanks for the comments fellas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, but you'll need to intervene with request parsing to give WordPress some help figuring out if it's a category or a tag.

The below code basically looks at the query and checks if `category_name` is set. If it is, it checks if there is actually a category with that slug. If the test fails, then it is assumed to be a tag, and the query vars are reset appropriately.

```
function wpd_categories_might_be_tags( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() && isset( $query->query_vars['category_name'] ) ){
        $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $query->query_vars['category_name'], 'category' );
        if( false == $term ){
            $query->query_vars['tag'] = $query->query_vars['category_name'];
            unset( $query->query_vars['category_name'] );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpd_categories_might_be_tags' );
```

The downsides to this are the extra processor cycles required to serve each of these requests, and you can never have a tag with a slug that is also a category.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, and I remember seeing something similar before but without getting it to work. Thanks mate!

Comment: nice one! in my case i had this problem with prefix and sub categories. rewritten your logic to test if the name is a category and replaced the category_name with the name. thanks!